# VS 2010 Setup project: how to get manufacturer name in Programs and Features

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, addremoveprograms

In my setup project in VS 2010, in the properties window, I have set the Manufacturer and ProductName properties. I have also set the Company property of the assemblies of my web application and class library. When I install, in Programs and Features, I want the "Manufacturer ProductName" listed. Now, I only get ProductName. I have other solutions that have setup projects that list the Manufacturer in Programs and Features, but I can't figure out what is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "ProductName" property to "Manufacturer ProductName"

Comment: Thanks. That is what I ended up doing. It looks like this is the best work-around.