# VS2010 installer - how to set [manufacturer] and other such properties

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I'm working on a VS2010 installer for a Windows Service project.
I want to set the [manufacturer] property for the project, but I can't see where it is located in 2010.

When I try to install currently, it converts [manufacturer] to 'Microsoft'.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I can tell from your response to @mrchief's answer that you're looking in the wrong place.  The assembly info source file sets the properties for the *installed* component.  But you probably want to change the name on the *setup* program.

In the Properties window for the Setup project, set the Author and Manufacturer properties.

[image]

Comment: I understand that.  I have VS2010 ultimate, and unfortunately, in the location you describe, that information is not there.  In there currently, I only have Configuration Properties, and Build under that...and those don't have this information.  Do you think I'm still looking in the wrong place, maybe have the wrong type of setup project, or does it just seem that is broken?

Comment: Wrong place, no idea where you're at.  Screenshot posted.

Comment: Thank you!  Don't know how I missed that, but I do have the flu, so maybe that impacted my judgement hehehe

Answer (score 14):

You should choose the Setup project in the Solution Explorer window and press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in `AssemblyCompany` attribute in your assembly info file

Also, this might help: [VS 2010 Setup project: how to get manufacturer name in Programs and Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078593/vs-2010-setup-project-how-to-get-manufacturer-name-in-programs-and-features)

Comment: Where are you checking? I can see the company being set.

Comment: Seems like you need to install it through a Windows deployment project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seykw6dt.aspx