# How to give author, publisher name in visual studio 2010 for VC++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I tried following plenty of questions in this forum to give author or publisher name when the ouptut .exe is double clicked. But I am unable to help myself. One of them which I followed was [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541362/vs2010-installer-how-to-set-manufacturer-and-other-such-properties) In the picture shown in the accepted answer, I am unable to find any manufacturer name. Also, I am not able to find "setup project in the solution explorer" which seems to have been told in many posts. Please can anyone help me giving answer step by step? I use visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> give author or publisher name when the ouptut .exe is double clicked

Double-clicking an EXE will start it.  If you want to see the version resource then you'll need to right-click it, Properties, Details.  Note how the linked question talked about a Setup project, not a C++ project.

To add a version resource to your EXE, you'll first need to add a resource file.  Check if your project already has a .rc file.  If not, use Project + Add New Item, Resource node, pick the "Resource File (.rc)" item template.

Double-click the .rc file in your project to open the Resource View window.  Right-click + Add Resource and pick Version.  Fill in the fields of the resource as needed.  Use the CompanyName field for the manufacturer.